# Selecting a subset of data in dplyr with 2 select verbs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I currently have this dplyr script to select certain data points. In the first select statement I am collecting all my needed columns. In the summarise statement I am creating some needed manipulations (basically concatenations). In my final select verb I am looking to select **ONLY** what is in my final select statement. However, when I view my data frame it still contains columns that were used in the summarise verb despite them not being selected in the final select ver. I would like to drop those columns. Below is a screenshot of the columns that are remaining but would like to exclude (in red)

```
data <-  qc_sales %>%
  mutate(Call_For_Price = ifelse(CFP_FLG == 1, "TRUE", "FALSE")) %>% 
 filter(    STR_NBR != '8119'
          , Opened_Quote_Flag == 1
          , LWK_TY_LY_FLG == 'TY'
          , MVNDR_NBR %in% c('60031167', '60688509', '60074051', '60148060', '60086898', '60080204')
          , !SUB_DEPT_NBR %in% c('0025','0028')) %>% 
   select(  QUOTE_DT
          , COM_ORDER_NBR  
          , STR_NBR
          , ST_CD
          , BRANCH_NM
          , MKT_NBR
          , MKT_NM
          , ASSC_FRST_NM
          , ASSC_LAST_NM
          , MAIN_STR_PHN_NBR
          , MVNDR_NBR
          , MVNDR_NM
          , SUB_DEPT_NBR
          , SUB_DEPT_DESC
          , PROD_DESC
          , ADD_PROD_DESC
          , Manufacturer_Model_NBR
          , Call_For_Price
          , QUOTE_DLRS) %>% 
  group_by(QUOTE_DT
          , COM_ORDER_NBR  
          , STR_NBR
          , ST_CD
          , BRANCH_NM
          , MKT_NBR
          , MKT_NM
          , ASSC_FRST_NM
          , ASSC_LAST_NM
          , MAIN_STR_PHN_NBR
          , MVNDR_NBR
          , MVNDR_NM
          , SUB_DEPT_NBR
          , SUB_DEPT_DESC
          , PROD_DESC
          , ADD_PROD_DESC
          , Manufacturer_Model_NBR
          , Call_For_Price
            ) %>% 
  summarise(Quote_Dollars =sum(QUOTE_DLRS)
          , Sub_Dept = MAX(CONCAT(SUB_DEPT_NBR,'-', SUB_DEPT_DESC))
          , Market_Nbr_Nm = MAX(CONCAT(MKT_NBR,'-', MKT_NM))
          , Associate_Name = MAX(CONCAT(ASSC_FRST_NM,'-', ASSC_LAST_NM))
          , MVNDR = MAX(CONCAT(MVNDR_NBR,'-', MVNDR_NM))) %>% 
  select(  QUOTE_DT
         , COM_ORDER_NBR
         , STR_NBR
         , ST_CD
         , BRANCH_NM
         , MAIN_STR_PHN_NBR
         , Market_Nbr_Nm
         , Associate_Name
         , MAIN_STR_PHN_NBR
         , Sub_Dept
         , MVNDR
         , PROD_DESC
         , ADD_PROD_DESC
         , Manufacturer_Model_NBR
         , Call_For_Price
         , Quote_Dollars) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Quote_Dollars)) %>%  
  collect()
```

[image]

In other words, I am not understanding why the highlighted columns are included in my data frame if they are not selected in the second select verb. I thought the order of operations in dplyr is basically descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this as follows. remove the grouping

```
...  
summarise(Quote_Dollars =sum(QUOTE_DLRS)
          , Sub_Dept = MAX(CONCAT(SUB_DEPT_NBR,'-', SUB_DEPT_DESC))
          , Market_Nbr_Nm = MAX(CONCAT(MKT_NBR,'-', MKT_NM))
          , Associate_Name = MAX(CONCAT(ASSC_FRST_NM,'-', ASSC_LAST_NM))
          , MVNDR = MAX(CONCAT(MVNDR_NBR,'-', MVNDR_NM))) %>% 
ungroup() %>%
...
```

*or*

```
...  
summarise(Quote_Dollars =sum(QUOTE_DLRS)
          , Sub_Dept = MAX(CONCAT(SUB_DEPT_NBR,'-', SUB_DEPT_DESC))
          , Market_Nbr_Nm = MAX(CONCAT(MKT_NBR,'-', MKT_NM))
          , Associate_Name = MAX(CONCAT(ASSC_FRST_NM,'-', ASSC_LAST_NM))
          , MVNDR = MAX(CONCAT(MVNDR_NBR,'-', MVNDR_NM))
          , .groups = "drop") %>% 
...
```

Comment: that did the trick, thank you! Can you elaborate why the `ungroup()` does the trick? When it comes to manipulating data I think in SQL and ungrouping isnt really a thing unless you want to do some funky stuff with subqueries

Comment: my English is not very good. I know this is a feature of `tidyverse`. I have faced this problem myself and have remembered that `group_by` should be removed when it is no longer needed.